# Help searching MYSQL database with a JOIN - possible self JOIN?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In a View i have a table of users combining data from multiple database tables. The important tables are Users and Invitations. Im performing a join

```
LEFT JOIN invitations ON (users.id = invitations.invitee_id)
```

which gives me access to `users.invitee_id`, but i also have dynamic search parameters in my query and i cant search for an inviter by email because the inviter email is determined by using the invitee_id joined with the users table on user id.

How can search for the inviter by email?

heres the entire query

```
    ["SELECT users.id, users.login, users.email, invitations.inviter_id, FROM users 
      LEFT JOIN invitations ON (users.id = invitations.invitee_id)
      WHERE (users.email LIKE ? OR users.id LIKE ? OR users.login LIKE ?)",
      "%#{params[:search]}%","%#{params[:search]}%","%#{params[:search]}%"]
```

**schema**

USERS: id, login, email

INVITATIONS: id, inviter_id, invitee_id

Comment: Please post a simplified schema.

Comment: Can you please run the following command on each of the tables you want to get information from: SHOW CREATE TABLE `yourtable`
Hopefully I will be able to help when I know the table structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join Users one more time

```
 .... LEFT JOIN users u2 ON (invitations.inviter_id = u2.user_id) 
 WHERE ... AND u2.user_name =[your condition]
```